# Select those who doesn't repeat

Tags: php, mysql

How to select like if I have columns with rows

```
column
row1
row1
row2
row3
row3
```

And when outputting all rows, only to output like..

```
row1
row2
row3
```

If there is rows with same value, I want to output them just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column) FROM TABLE
```

or

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE
GROUP BY column
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `fieldname` FROM `mytable`
```